# Center waveform amplitude to 0?

Tags: sound-design, audacity

[image: I would like the top track of audio to vertically center around 0db like the track below it.]

I would like the top track of audio to vertically center around 0db like the track below it in audacity. For some reason it is skewered to to positive side. I don't know how this happened.

Answer (score 1):

It's DC offset. Apply a DC filter or a high-pass filter to remove.